# Is there a way to have 2 functions with the same name?

Tags: javascript, function, overloading

[image]

I am trying to achieve a similar effect where I have 2 functions with the same name but they accept a different number of arguments. I know overloading is not possible in javascript and that the function that was defined last will be the one called everytime, however I want to know if there is a way to do so. I know I can name them differently, check for number of arguments, have defaults params, etc. but I am trying to avoid all that.

Comment: *but I am trying to avoid all that.* No other option, that's what `drawImage` is doing (except in native code, not in JS)

Comment: @CertainPerformance But how does it have 2 functions with the same name and different number of parameters?

Comment: It's the same function, but with the browser's intellisense

Comment: *I know overloading is not possible in javascript and that the function that was defined last will be the one called everytime, however I want to know if there is a way to do so* - this is like saying *I know cars can't fly, but I want to know if there's a way to make **my** car fly*

Comment: @CertainPerformance Are you saying that the console is programmed to show it like that based on some conditions and since its native code (saw the edit now), we don't know how to let it know?

Comment: just make a function with the maximum number of arguments it needs ... then, the code in the function can determine how many arguments were passed and do whatever depending on the number of arguments - note: calling a javascript function with more or less arguments than are declared won't cause an error

Comment: It's pretty much as simple as checking `arguments.length`

Answer (score 1):

The `drawImage` function that you are using as an example isn't just with pure javascript. The autocomplete thing that says `**image**, x`... on the top and `**image**, sx`... on the bottom needs typescript or typescript definitions. If you don't care about the editor stuff then there is a way to do this in javascript.

**Example With Javascript**

You need *something* to differentiate the two different functions. For example both of the functions can't have exactly the same arguement types.

Let's say that you want to have a function that does two things. If a `string` is given, it adds `" - Yes"` To the string. If a `number` is given then it multiplies it by 2.

```
function multiUse(arg1){
    if(typeof(arg1) == "string"){
        //Do some stuff
        return arg1 + " - Yes";
    }
    else{
        //Do other stuff
        return arg1 * 2;
    }
}
```

Here we have a function that does two different things by calling the same function.

**Example Using Typescript**

If you want to have a proper typescript overload function, then this is how you would do it

```
function multiUse(string: string): string;
function multiUse(number: number): number;
function multiUse(arg1: any): any {
    if(typeof(arg1) == "string"){
        //Do some stuff
        return arg1 + " - Yes";
    }
    else{
        //Do other stuff
        return arg1 * 2;
    }
};
```

After this you have to convert the typescript file into a javascript file. The two ways of doing this are basically the same.